# How to create a normal running program? Because my program is run eternaly and wont stop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My English is very bad, but i'm try to explain my problem.
I want to create a small program on bash in which the user will have to guess the numbers. But my program has no end.

I'm novice on bash scripting, but i try to get better everyday.
I'm using CentOS 7. I go to /usr/bin/local and create some file, give him chmod +x and open with gedit:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#This script should ask us our name and play the game "Guess the Number" with us.

echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "Hello $name"
echo "I want to play $ name with you, you have to guess the number from 1 to 10)"
echo "Are you ready?"
read rdy


answer=$(( answer = $RANDOM % 10 ))


read -p "Enter your number: " variant 
     while [ $answer != $variant ]; do

if [ $answer -gt $variant ]; then 
     echo "Your number is bigger, try again"

elif [ $answer -lt $variant ]; then
     echo "Your number is smaller, try again"

  continue

fi

done

eternal "Your number is smaller/bigger"
until you press ctrl+c
```

What I need to do, please help. I know non amateurs don't likes novices but i need your help, show me my mistake, and i can get better. Thanks!

Comment: `read -p "Enter your number: " variant 
     while [ $answer != $variant ];` you read the variant and inspect it in loop endlessy, without every changing it. I guess you want to read the variant inside the loop. Also, run your script via https://www.shellcheck.net/ and remember to quote your variables.

Comment: thank you very much! i need to practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "Hello $name"
echo "I want to play  with you, you have to guess the number from 1 to 10"


answer=$(( $RANDOM % 10 ))

while true
do
    read -p "Enter your number: " variant
    if [ "$answer" -gt "$variant" ]; then
        echo "The number is bigger, try again"

    elif [ "$answer" -lt "$variant" ]; then
        echo "The number is smaller, try again"
    else
        break;
    fi

done
echo "Yes, the answer was ${answer}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
read -p "Enter your number: " variant
```

before the `while` loop.

Inside the loop you never change the `variant`, so the original value is re-used in the `while` condition. For Eternity.

You can start with `variant=-1` and move the `read`inside the loop or do something like @xiawi.